# JS - Given array of objects, can I return an array of just selected properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

Given an array like this:

```
[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}]
```

Is there any (easy) way to return the an array of the same objects, but just with a selected property?
E.g. let's say I only wanted to retain property "a" ...

```
[{a: 1}, {a: 3} {a: 5}]
```

Comment: `let result = arr.map(({a}) => ({a}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution (little bit more generic than Ibrahim's comment):

```js
const a = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}, {a: 5, b: 6}];

const f = (arr, prop) => a.map(({ [prop]: propToKeep }) => ({ [prop]: propToKeep }));

console.log(f(a, 'a'));
```